# METEOR Accounts UI sign in button isn't showing up in Mobile App wrapper

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, meteor

I created my project and deployed it at

```
jott.meteor.com
```

and I am trying to port it to Android using ["Building Mobile Apps."](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/buildingmobileapps)
When I do so, the Sign In button in the top right doesn't show up which uses the Accounts-UI package.

[See these screenshots!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUPsU.jpg)

```
<div id="a" class="container">
    <div id="b" class="starter-template">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="jotttitle"><span id="jottspan">Jott</span></div>
            <div id="login">{{> loginButtons}}</div>
        </div>
        <br/>{{> textGoesHere}}
    </div>
</div>
```

It's ugly, I'm working on that, but this is the HTML for where the {{> loginButtons}} is. I did change some of the CSS for the popup, but I'm not sure if that would affect it. If you need anymore info, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I can't view imgur from work, but could you put some text around the `{{> loginButtons}}` like this: `<div id="login">XXX{{> loginButtons}}YYY</div>` to see if the div is rendering?  Also, does android have some sort of debug mode like the Chrome Dev Tools?  If so, use that to check your DOM to see if the contents of `{{> loginButtons}}` are rendered or skipped.  It may just be that the images/css/etc are not coming down yet or are having some issue coming does, so the DOM is just not presented correctly.

Comment: Sorry about imgur... I need a higher rep to add pictures :( I tried your advice by adding the "XXX   YYY" and the "XXX and YYY" Showed up, but the Sign In button, which should have shown up between them, did not show up... as for am Android equivalent to check the DOM I'm not really sure if that exists... maybe I'll check StackOverflow for it!

Comment: Well, in essence your "app" is really just a page using the  equivalent web component to display, similar to what Phonegap does.  I am not sure if maybe the Android dev emulator might be of use.  Again, I have never written an Android app yet so I am only vaguely familiar with the tools.  I would think you should be able to run your generated app in the Emulator and set/view breakpoints and such.

Comment: So here's something interesting, I tried running it through the Android emulator and boom! The Sign-in button was there! However, when I tried running it on my actual phone... no Sign-In button :( very strange... might be an issue with Meteor, itself.

Comment: This seems to be pointing to an inconsistency with the browser on your phone.  Do you have access to any other Android devices you could maybe try out?

Comment: Another thought...when you had the 'XXX' and 'YYY' test code around the buttons template call, did it have a space between them or where they butted up together?  If there was a space, what happened when you click it?  Could it be a CSS issue?  What about using jQuery to dump the DOM out to the page for verification?

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. When I launched it on my phone, the server it was looking for was localhost:3000; what meteor uses. I set it to the deployed website (https://jott.meteor.com) POOF it worked!

Comment: Fantastic!  I thought this might seem like an issue with rendering.  Didn't make sense why the DOM would not render on the phone but worked fine in the browser and the emulator.  Instead of hard-coding the hostname, thought, I'd recommend using relative pathing.  This way it works everywhere.

Comment: How would I use relative pathing in Meteor? Also, since this answer was solved in this comment, what do I do for the correct answer?

Comment: Relative pathing is not a Meteor thing, its how you build your URL.  For instance, I can do this: `<a href="http://example.com/some/path/example.html">Click Me</a>` or I could do: `<a href="/some/path/example.html">Click Me</a>`, assuming the link was in a page already hosted on example.com.  The difference is that the first will ALWAYS point to example.com, whereas the second will point to that page on any site it's hosted on, allowing it to be more portable.  If you are using Iron Router you can add more portability by using their `{{pathFor}}` helper, at least for the routes that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/How-to-submit-your-Android-app-to-Play-Store)
link really helped me figure this out, along with user [CodeChimp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1278839/codechimp)!

It turns out that if I just run

```
meteor run android-device
```

it wasn't working because I never specified the server for the mobile app to look for.

I needed to do this instead:

```
meteor run android-device --mobile-server https://example.com
```

which, for me, looked like:

```
meteor run android-device --mobile-server https://jott.meteor.com
```

That ended up working!

See [this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration#running-on-a-physical-device) too for other resources!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but when testing app over the wifi network on Android device, the problem was the firewall. Opening the port 3000 solved the problem ..

So try, disable Firewall or open port 3000